# Whenever I attempt to import scapy.py, it gives me an error message. Why does my scapy not import?

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I cannot import scapy.py as it gives the following error message.

```
`from scapy.all import *

pac = IP()/ICMP()
pac.show()`
```

Which shows:

```
    from scapy.all import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy'
```

I then try to add the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages')
from scapy.all import *

pac = IP()/ICMP()
pac.show()
```

However, the same error persists.

I have tried to uninstall and re-install scapy.py but again the same error pops up whenever I try and run my code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The definitive solution .You have to download like this.

┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/kali/Public/Stackoverflow/MyProject]

└─# ls
MyProject.py

┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/kali/Public/Stackoverflow/MyProject]

└─# ls -la

total 16

drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Feb 29 20:50 .

drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 29 20:49 ..

drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 29 20:50 .idea

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 29 20:50 MyProject.py

drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb 29 20:49 .venv

┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/kali/Public/Stackoverflow/MyProject]

└─# cd  .venv

┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/…/Public/Stackoverflow/MyProject/.venv]

└─# ls

bin    lib     pyvenv.cfg

┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/…/Public/Stackoverflow/MyProject/.venv]

└─# cd bin

┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/…/Stackoverflow/MyProject/.venv/bin]

└─# ls

activate       activate.fish   activate.ps1        pip        pip-3.11              python   python3.11       wheel3          wheel3.11
activate.csh   activate.nu     activate_this.py   pip3   pip3.11    python3  wheel
wheel-3.11

┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/…/Stackoverflow/MyProject/.venv/bin]

└─# source  activate

┌──(.venv)─(root㉿kali)-[/home/…/Stackoverflow/MyProject/.venv/bin]

└─# pip  install  scapy

Collecting scapy

Using cached scapy-2.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Installing collected packages: scapy

Successfully installed scapy-2.5.0

┌──(.venv)─(root㉿kali)-[/home/…/Stackoverflow/MyProject/.venv/bin]

└─# deactivate

┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/…/Stackoverflow/MyProject/.venv/bin]

└─#

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).